# 1-Sample KS-Test always give me .000 Asymp. Sig. in SPSS

Tags: spss, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P-Ky-TLHDss) tutorial and trying to perform `Analyze→Nonparametric Tests→Legacy Dialogs→1-Sample K-S` but Asymp. Sig. is .000 for every variable. Am I missing something? Data set that I am using can be found [here](http://www.columbia.edu/itc/hs/pubhealth/remler/8502/client_edit/SPSS.html) . My data set is under number 18. Also, I have a little `c` beside to .000 that says Lilliefors Significance Correction.

Answer (score 1):

Questions about code are off topic here, but several statistics packages will use 0.000 when it really should be < 0.001 (or < 0.0005).  They are rounding the value to 3 digits after the 0.